# Comparison of regression methods with MATLAB

Tags: regression, bayesian, neural-networks, gaussian-process

I am writing a chapter of my thesis, where I try to establish the relationship
between regressors (512 x 8) and response (512 x 1) in my data.

I have been suggested to use three regression methods:

1. Bayesian linear (`tapas_vblm`),
2. Gaussian process (a non-parametric probabilistic regressor; `GPML`
   package),
3. Artificial Neural Network (MATLAB, Feedforward Multilayer Perceptron
   Neural Network, **MLPNN**, with a backpropagation reinforcement learning
   training algorithm—scaled conjugate gradient).

Once I trained the models with 85% of the data, for cross-validation I compared them with the remaining 15%, and determined over the testing data the:
- coefficient of determination
- root mean square error
- mean square error
- mean average error

My question is how to theoretically compare the three methods (cost function,
given priors, etc.)?

Comment: Surely you mean mean absolute error? And what kind of answer are you looking for? Also since you mention software, could you please be more precise which software? I for one am not aware of tapas_vblm or gpml packages. Is this python, R, matlab, Stata, SPSS, SAS or something else?

Comment: These are unlikely to be equally flexible in their ability to fit the data. You should take that into account somehow, eg w/ cross validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with those regression methods. However, I also suggest ridge regression which is fairly easy to use. 
Given your data are in a 2-dim format where 1st dim are instances and 2nd dim are datapoints as well as a target 1-dim vector with target values:

`ridgeModel = ridge( YTrain, XTrain(:,:), 1, 0); % parameters are necessary
for i=1:length(XTest) 
   YPredict(i) = XTest(i,:)*ridgeModel(2:end) + ridgeModel(1); 
end`

For better comparison of regression methods, I direct you towards AUC-value analysis by receiver operating characteristics. Fawcett (2005) wrote an excellent [introductory article](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/workshops/mir2009/references/ROCintro.pdf).